# I want to add specific amount to a element on every oninput

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a range slider, but I'm having a issue oninput I want to add specific amount in another amount it should increase amount on every oninput of slider. I want to increase amount on button by $150 in $2000 and on $45000 whenever slider range takes an input? If there's someone who could help me to make it happen if you can then that'd be a great help!

```js
var range = document.getElementById("range");
var val = document.getElementById("value");
var vvv = document.getElementById("vvv");
var saved = document.getElementById("saved");
val.innerHTML = "$" + range.value + "K";

range.oninput = function() {
  val.innerHTML = "$" + this.value + "K";
}
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
abbr,
address,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
samp,
small,
strong,
sub,
sup,
var,
b,
i,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}


/* change colours to suit your needs */

ins {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* change colours to suit your needs */

mark {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title],
dfn[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: help;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* change border colour to suit your needs */

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input,
select {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.head h2 {
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.range-slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(90% - (73px));
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(214, 214, 214) 60%, rgb(214, 214, 214) 60%);
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.range-slider__range:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}

.values h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #636363;
}

.values p {
  color: #24A98F;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn button {
  padding: 15px 80px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #58DBC2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #45CDB1;
}

.chk p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #6C6363;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}

@media(max-width:500px) {
  .chk p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #6C6363;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .head h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media(max-width:440px) {
  .head h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media(max-width:503px) {
  .btn button {
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #58DBC2;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #45CDB1;
  }
}

@media(max-width:351px) {
  .btn button {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #58DBC2;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #45CDB1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99f2762a6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="heading">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="head">
          <h2>How Much Will You Save?</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-l-12">
        <div class="range-slider">

          <input id="range" class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="150" step="5" min="150" max="1000">
          <span id="value" class="range-slider__value">0</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="words text-center mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
        <div class="values">
          <h2>Homie Flat Fee </h2>
          <p>What is this?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-2 mb-sm-2 mb-md-2 mb-lg-0 mt-3 mt-sm-0 mt-md-3">
        <div class="values">
          <h2>VS</h2>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 ">
        <div class="values">
          <h2 id="saved">$4500K</h2>
          <p>Traditional agent commission*
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="btn">
          <button>Click to Save <span id="vvv">$2000</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="chk text-sm-center text-md-center">
          <p>Savings calculations based on difference between 3% listing agent commission and Homie’s flat listing fee. Savings may vary.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I can't seem to parse the phrase "increase amount ... by $150 in $2000 and on $45000". if you want to increase by 150, use `step="150"`...

Comment: @AsH RaJpOoT I think you need to clarify your wording. It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Can you give a few examples of the expected input and output (like: when user slides to "$600K" this should happen...)

Comment: Run the code snippet
you'll see that, I used step ="5", on every single oninput it takes 5 !
Now what I want is, Whenever slider takes an input I want to add $150 amount in button in which it says "click here to save $2000" after one input on button it shoukd says "click here to save $2150" and so on!

Comment: So, after every slide input, value keeps on changing  by $150,, after one input it should make it $2150 after second sldie input it should be $2300

Answer (score 0):

```
let vvvMultiplier = .03
let savedMultiplier = .013
let template = (value) => {
  return `$${value}K`
}
range.oninput = function () {
  let value = Number(this.value)
  let inputValue = value
  let vvvValue = Math.floor(value * vvvMultiplier)
  let savedValue = Math.floor(value * savedMultiplier)
  let inputText = template(inputValue)
  let vvvText = template(vvvValue)
  let savedText = template(savedValue)
  val.innerHTML = inputText
  vvv.innnerHTML = vvvText
  saved.innerHTML = savedText
}
```

Comment: Really need help